# The ways to programmatically like a photo on instagram?

Tags: swiftui

Is there any way that we can `like` someones photos `programmatically` if we have the public photo URL?.
The interface I'm trying to develop will be look like that I will log in to `my insta account` from `swiftui program`. Then I will enter a `public photo URL` of some other person, when I `click a button` it should trigger a `like` to the that `public photo of the URL`.

Example public photo URL : https://www.instagram.com/p/AABBCC123

[image]

Comment: take a look at [`UILicious`](https://uilicious.com) - that will let you go to the page and then like the photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ways You Can Do It :

1. You get an API to do it
2. Or Create a Web scraping in the background or somewhere on the server and then send back data
3. Last Analyse/Debug Instagram to get what the server is doing and where the request is going with headers and all that cookies (it's awful)

Edit:
Here's how:
Firstly there's an API you can make: `https://www.instagram.com/web/likes/{imageid}/like/`

You need all headers :

```
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 0
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie: mid=YqCI-QAEAA....
origin: https://www.instagram.com
referer: https://www.instagram.com/p/...
sec-ch-prefers-color-scheme: dark
sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
viewport-width: 1280
x-asbd-id: 198387
x-csrftoken: 9MaKefC5EVoWP3He9b9vnS8f8fq87Fgx
x-ig-app-id: 5642....
x-ig-www-claim: .....
x-instagram-ajax: 1005
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

If you want all data from his profile you make a request to Instagram API : `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username={}`

Headers you need:

```
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cookie:
origin: https://www.instagram.com
referer: https://www.instagram.com/
sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHT...
x-asbd-id: 19...
x-csrftoken: 9MaK....
x-ig-app-id: 9366...
x-ig-www-claim: hmac.AR2BQU9Tfnj..
```

You may get x-csrftoken at the login page for validation.

Comment: thanks for the information. I'll use this info as the base. I think more better way is to use an inbuilt browser and it will get the cookies automatically anyways. Then have to find a way to which html code triggers the `like` etc? or is there any better way with inbuilt browser in the app? I think APIs have limitations.

Comment: Yeah! API have many limitations. I don't know about `swift` but `mechanize` module if available in `swift` as in `python` then you don't need browser to handle cookies and also if you use this then you have check whole `DOM` content is loaded or not as Instagram load content dynamically. 
If you are beginning then it would be grate to use `inbuilt browser` or something like `headless browser`.
After this you have to find which button have to trigger.

Comment: Did you find it? I got the way to do... Check the answer I have edited it.